# Query grouped by single column

Tags: php, mysql, select, group-by

I'd like to spit out database results which are grouped by a parent ID.

I have the following table:

```
`pages`
    `id` int
    `parent_id` int
    `title` varchar
```

Some of the `pages` have a `parent_id` of 0, meaning they do not have a parent.

Lets say I have the following rows in the `pages` table:

```
id | parent_id | title
1  | 0         | Colors
2  | 1         | Red
3  | 1         | Green
4  | 1         | Blue
5  | 0         | Devices
6  | 5         | Mobile
7  | 5         | Desktop
8  | 5         | Tablet
```

Given these rows, I want to output the following on my PHP page:

```
Colors
    Red
    Green
    Blue

Devices
    Mobile
    Desktop
    Tablet
```

I know that I can use a query to get the rows with a `parent_id` of 0, and then another query to get the rows with a `parent_id` of that `id`.

Is it possible to write this as a single query?

Comment: Can you also share those two query ? It will easy to understand what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it's not pretty: You have a hierarchical data structure (parent/child), and to arrange things in that fashion in a single query requires recursive queries, which mysql doesn't support.

You'll need to do a self-join for every level of hierarchy you have:

```
SELECT parent.*, child.*
FROM yourtable AS parent
LEFT JOIN yourtable AS child ON parent.id = child.parent_id
```

For every level of your tree, you'll need another join/alias as above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking the following solution:

```
SELECT 
  t1.title as parent, t2.title
FROM 
  pages AS t1
LEFT JOIN pages AS t2 
  ON t1.id = t2.parent_id
WHERE
  t2.id IS NOT NULL
```

You will get the result as like:

```
parent  title
Colors  Red
Colors  Green
Colors  Blue
Devices Mobile
Devices Desktop
Devices Tablet
```

Now you have to arrange it in you php side.

Here is the sqlfiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/11fa6/3